# Fishpig not Showing Category Page

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, fishpig

On my Magento fishpig/wordpress blog page on my website, categories and links to that category show up on the top nav bar, on the blog titles themselves.

These should lead to a category page with a list of all blog posts in that category, but they do not. Instead they are going to a `/blog/community/blogs/category-name` page which returns a 404 Not found errors (as that page in the Wordpress backend doesn't exist) as opposed to hitting the `categories/view.phtml` file in magento. I do not know why this might be, but I suspect something is wrong in the Fishpig router protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension uses your WordPress 'home' URL + the category prefix + the category slug to generate this URL so my advice would be to check these values.

You can find the category prefix at WordPress Admin > Settings > Permalinks.